# How to push a single commit to a new remote?

Tags: git

I want to push a single commit to a new remote

My local log: A -> B -> C -> D  where A is the initial commit

Usual workflow for pushing local repository:

- create project at server
- `git add remote origin ...`
- `git push -u origin master` or `git push -u --all origin`

My remote log: A -> B -> C -> D

---

`git push -u origin A:master` do not work - why?

**Since people are interested for the *why***
[Gitlab](https://www.gitlab.com/gitlab-ce/) don't trigger push event web hooks on the initial commit (not sure if bug or feature..)

Comment: Which is your newest commit? A or D?

Comment: @GregHewgill D is ofc the newest commit ;)

Comment: Can you post the error output?

Comment: What's the value of pushing just that commit?

Comment: @DonBranson: Sometimes repositories contain sensitive information, etc. and you want the public version being free of this. For instance some fellow students try to push grammar fix commits back in history and thus denying they made such mistake... :P

Comment: @CommuSoft Perhaps, but you'll need a plan to keep those other commits private going into the future. That probably means a branch from A that excludes sensitive commits. So, make the branch now and push that.

Comment: Would git cherry-pick do the trick?  I.e., first checkout the remote branch, and then cherry-pick the branch which has A, B,C,D commits to grab the commits of interest?  And then push out that branch.

Comment: Isn't cherrypicking designed to apply the diff on another commit? I thing @Lucas wants the state after the master without the entire history.

Comment: Good point.  I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new repository:

```
cd ..
mkdir -p newrepo
git init
cd ../oldrepo
git fast-export master~1..master | (cd ../newrepo && git fast-import && git checkout)
```

Then add a remote to the second repository:

```
cd ../newrepo
git remote add origin someremote
git push --all
git remote add old ../oldrepo
git fetch old
git merge old/master
git push
```

You can of course also filter branches, etc.

Comment: I've never used or even seen fast-*port before. Tried this but the export command don't export anything.

Comment: What if you use `master~1..master`?

Comment: yup works.. Makes it even easier to merge in compare to my rough-and-ready solution. accepted! But add the remote add + merge part to your answer

Answer (score 1):

`cherry-pick` and `merge` is not the best solution but it works for now.

```
mkdir newRepo
cd newRepo
git init
git remote add old ../oldRepo
git remote add origin <remote repository>
git fetch old
git cherry-pick <commit SHA>
git push -u origin master
git merge old/master
# merge by hand if neccessary
# git add <manually merged files>
git commit
git rebase
# check result
git log --oneline
git push origin master
```